# Pentaho PDI calculating the total sum of all entries in a column

Tags: pentaho-data-integration

I need to calculate the sum of the entire column and print it as a new field in the excel file output using Pentaho 9.3 PDI.I’ve tried using the formula function and gave the formula sum([Salary]). Salary is the field name that I want to calculate the total sum of but it only sums each respective record and displays it. I need the sum of that particular entire field.

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to use the **Group By** step, to sum the salary on all the rows instead of row by row.

If you need the salary by employee, for example, then before using the **Group By** step, you need to use a **Sort** step to sort by employee all the incoming rows, and afterwards use the **Group By** step indicating that you wish to group by employee in the corresponding part of the step.